# OAuth - "redirect uri mismatch"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth, google-signin, redirect-uri-mismatch

I've been battling with this Google Login for a while now(+2 weeks) and pulling my hair because I don't understand what is causing this error for me.

Context: Rails 7 API trying to send a HTTP request to eXchange my Authorization Code for an access token from Google.
Error: **`"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",`**

```
GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

# Redirect URI
REDIRECT_URI=https://63cd-106-185-157-124.ngrok.io/auth/google_oauth2/callback
```

[Google Console]
[image]
[Ngrok Running]
[image]

My method getting the authorization code and then sending the request:

```
 def self.get_access_token(auth_code)
    conn = Faraday.new
    response = conn.post(ENV['GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL']) do |req|
      req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      req.body = URI.encode_www_form(
        code: auth_code,
        client_id: ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'],
        client_secret: ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: ENV['REDIRECT_URI']
      )
    end

    if response.status == 200
      puts "Successfully authorized code and got access_token"
      puts "Response body: #{response.body}"
    else
      puts "Failed to get access_token."
      puts "Response status: #{response.status}"
      puts "Response body: #{response.body}"
    end
  end
```

I started out with sending my request with this redirect_uri: `http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback` whichis also added in my console, but it gave me the same error `error: "redirect_uri_mismatch`

I changed over to using ngrok and HTTPS as I read somewhere that it is required?

- Restarted my app plenty of times
- Waited for over 24 hours after adding my URI
- Tried restarting from scratch

Grateful for any help. Hope someone can point out something stupid I missed.

Comment: Debugging tip: Inspect the requests on the developer console of your browser. Check preserve requests option. On login redirect copy the url and observe it, what do you see in the redirect_uri parameter? That uri must be set in google console.

Comment: @BishakhGhosh

Thank you for the suggestion! Not sure I understand you though. Currently I'm only passing my authentication in the backend, and not via any browser at all so unfortunately I can't check that. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: How are you getting the authorization code then? As per your description, ngrok / https etc., does not matter. Use the same redirect_url you used to get the authorization code  in `ENV['REDIRECT_URI']`

Comment: @BishakhGhosh

I can't thank you enough, you were absolutely right. When starting the authorization on the frontend, the library I used generated a redirect uri which was never 'visible' to me unless I copied the url from the browser directly. Copying that and then using that as the redirect URI in my backend API and Google Console as well solved it.

Again, thank you!